# Integrate KoliBri web-components in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, web-component

I am trying to integrate KoliBri web-components (https://github.com/public-ui/kolibri) in a Vaadin project. I followed the documentation for web components integration (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/create-ui/web-components) but I was not successful.

I want to integrate a KoliBri-button (kol-button) and therefor created getter and setter methods for the required properties of the button. When loading the website, the kol-button-component is loaded successfully from the .js file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMhOE.png)

But the kol-button element in the DOM is empty and won´t show up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/negNc.png)

Here is my KolButton.java:

```
package com.example.application.views.helloworld;    
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Synchronize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.NpmPackage;

@Tag("kol-button")
@NpmPackage(value = "@public-ui/components", version = "1.1.10")
@JsModule("@public-ui/components/dist/components/kol-button")

public class KolButton extends Component {
public boolean getLabel() {
    return getElement().getProperty("_label", false);
}
public void setLabel(String label) {
    getElement().setProperty("_label", label);
}
public void setVariant(String variant) {
    getElement().setProperty("_variant", variant);
}
public boolean getVariant() {
    return getElement().getProperty("_variant", false);
 }
}
```

And the view.java:

```
package com.example.application.views.helloworld;
import com.example.application.views.MainLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteAlias;

@PageTitle("Hello World")
@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {
public HelloWorldView() {
    var kolButton = new KolButton();
    kolButton.setLabel("TestText");
    kolButton.setVariant("danger");

    setVerticalComponentAlignment(Alignment.END, kolButton);
    add(kolButton);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not shared your Java code, so your information does not reveal if you have `@Tag` annotation correctly there, or what you have put in `@NpmPackage` annotations in order to import kol-button files and possible other dependencies needed.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Hopefully this will give you some more information!

Comment: Your code looks ok. I tried it and it does not work. I added specific dependencies to stencil library, public-ui/thmes and public-ui/core. But still seems not to work. It could be that the library is exclusively made for React, but I am not 100% sure. If your motivation is to use these components due Accessibility, I think you are not doing productive work. Vaadin's component library offers premium Accessibility features in Vaadin 23 and newer versions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and your help trying to fix my problem